# Can webkit show flash banners?

Tags: flash, webkit, click

I'm pretty sure the answer is no but I just wanted to confirm whether or not webkit can show flash banners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webkit sure can show Flash banners... Open up just about any Flash-based site in Safari and you'll see them. Are you referring to Mobile Safari (Safari on the iPhone/iPad)? If that's the case, then you'd be correct - it does not show Flash banners.